# Favorite tools for monitoring cache for windows?

Tags: caching, profiling, monitor

I am trying to profile my application but apparently it is too large for the profiler to even process.  I am using IBM Quantify and suspect the same problem will show up if I try to use a different profiling tool.

So I'm looking for a program that will monitor cache and i/o activity and performance that will run in the background and won't have to attach to a certain application.

Also, I am aware of a memclear.exe for XP but it requires some development pack?  Does anyone know how to get this to work or does anyone know of an equivalent application that works as a stand alone?

Thanks in advance,
Jbu

**edit**: using windows XP

Answer (score 1):

You can try using perfmon.  If the existing counters don't meet your needs then you can add your own counters.